# How to open a project folder in Spyder IDE?

Tags: python, django, spyder

I am new to Spyder after VS Code and now want to open my Django project folder. I'm following these steps:

`Projects > New project > Existing directory > Create` but Spyder opens some `temp.py` which after closing opens `untitled0.py`,`untitled1.py`,`untitled2.py` and so on. How can I see my project structure, files as in VS Code ?

Answer (score 10):

On the right side of IDE there is a window containing some subwindows like `IPython console`, `Variable explorer`, `Help` and so on. We are clicking on `Files` and see our project folder.